# Why doesn't my bubble sort work properly?

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

I have been trying to create a BubbleSort to sort out an array. The array's name is UserNameArray, the format of the array is . The  is a six-character string of numerals and the  is a string. An example would look like this: 123456James.

My program sorts out some of the data but it fails to run a couple of times to really sort out all the data.

```
UserNameArray = ["234511Jack","734636Dan","237894Daniel", "124119James", "000001Test","999999Donald"]
def BubbleSort():
    for i in range(0,len(UserNameArray)-1):
        for j in range(0,i):
            UserID = int(UserNameArray[j][0:5])
            UserIDNext = int(UserNameArray[j+1][0:5])
            print(i,j)
            print(UserID,UserIDNext)
            if UserIDNext < UserID:
                store = UserNameArray[j]
                UserNameArray[j] = UserNameArray[j+1]
                UserNameArray[j+1] = store
            print(UserNameArray)
BubbleSort()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
UserNameArray = ["234511Jack","734636Dan","237894Daniel", "124119James", "000001Test","999999Donald"]
def BubbleSort():
    for i in range(len(UserNameArray)-1,0,-1): // you use wrong direction here
        for j in range(0,i):
            UserID = int(UserNameArray[j][0:5])
            UserIDNext = int(UserNameArray[j+1][0:5])
            print(i,j)
            print(UserID,UserIDNext)
            if UserIDNext < UserID:
                store = UserNameArray[j]
                UserNameArray[j] = UserNameArray[j+1]
                UserNameArray[j+1] = store
            print(UserNameArray)
BubbleSort()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UserNameArray = [
    "234511Jack",
    "734636Dan",
    "237894Daniel", 
    "124119James", 
    "000001Test",
    "999999Donald"
]
def BubbleSort():
    for i in range(0,len(UserNameArray)-1):
        for j in range(0,len(UserNameArray)-1-i):
            UserID = int(UserNameArray[j][0:5])
            UserIDNext = int(UserNameArray[j+1][0:5])
            if UserIDNext < UserID:
                store = UserNameArray[j]
                UserNameArray[j] = UserNameArray[j+1]
                UserNameArray[j+1] = store

BubbleSort()
print(UserNameArray)
```

! for j in range(0,len(UserNameArray)-1-i):

Comment: Please consider explaining your solution to the questioner what conditions need to change and why.

Comment: principle [link](https://github.com/hustcc/JS-Sorting-Algorithm/blob/master/1.bubbleSort.md)

Comment: "i" controls the total number of loops, "j" controls the number of single comparisons, the end of an inner loop, the last value in the list is the maximum value, so "j-i" minus the confirmed maximum value @ThomasLang